# How do I specify “Run with highest privileges” in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks, task

When I use the GUI Task Scheduler, I can easily check the "Run with highest privileges" checkbox.

I found no such option in the VBScript command line too, however.

Is there a way to do that from the VBScript?

How to add this script this two feature?

[image]

Example VBScript: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383665%28v%3DVS.85%29.aspx

Privileges: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382076%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This VBScript code automates the SchTasks.exe program and should demonstrate what you want to do.  To get a list of the switches for creating tasks with SchTasks, you can run this:

```
schtasks.exe /create /?
```

You still have to run the below script from an administrative command-prompt to be able to create a task with "Highest" privileges.  Also, if you wish to use an account other than the system account, you should use the /RP switch.  If you're fully automating it, you may wish to use the /F switch as well to force overwriting an existing task.  Otherwise it may hang while waiting for user input.

```
Option Explicit

Dim WshShell, strWinDir, strCmdLine, lngExitCode
Const OpenAsCurrentWindowIsOpened = 10, WaitForExit = True

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strWinDir = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WINDIR%")

strCmdLine = strWinDir & "\System32\SCHTASKS.exe /create /SC DAILY /TN ""My VBScript Task"" /TR """ & strWinDir & "\System32\calc.exe"" /RL HIGHEST /RU ""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"""

lngExitCode = WshShell.Run(strCmdLine, OpenAsCurrentWindowIsOpened, WaitForExit)

If lngExitCode = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Success"
Else
  WScript.Echo "Failed with error code " & CStr(lngExitCode)
End If
```

Comment: Working XP/Vista/Windows 7 ? (x86/x64 both)

Comment: Why don't you try it?  I would expect this to work on Vista and Windows 7.  As the concept of "highest privileges" didn't exist for XP, you may have to make adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to interactively run VBScripts in admin mode, you just have to run CSCRIPT from a command-line that is already running in "Admin mode".  For example, click Start, type cmd, wait a few seconds..., right-click cmd.exe and choose "Run as Administrator".  Then when you run CSCRIPT from that command-line it will run with highest privileges already.  Note you have to be logged-in with an admin user account already.

Or are you asking how you automate creating new scheduled tasks in VBScript with those options set?

Comment: YES! THIS =>
Or are you asking how you automate creating new scheduled tasks in VBScript with those options set?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to admin mode, try this:

```
Dim ObjShell
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ObjShell.Run "runas.exe"
```

Since `CMD in Admin mode` is just `runas.exe`, you can run it through WScript.Shell(`ObjShell.Run`).
This way is more effecient because if you want to run a command line you can simply do this:

```
ObjShell.Run "runas.exe /K (command goes here)"
```